# Why does golang RGBA.RGBA() method use | and <<?

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

In the golang color package, there is a method to get r,g,b,a values from an `RGBA` object:

```
func (c RGBA) RGBA() (r, g, b, a uint32) {
    r = uint32(c.R)
    r |= r << 8
    g = uint32(c.G)
    g |= g << 8
    b = uint32(c.B)
    b |= b << 8
    a = uint32(c.A)
    a |= a << 8
    return
}
```

If I were to implement this simple function, I would just write this

```
func (c RGBA) RGBA() (r, g, b, a uint32) {
    r = uint32(c.R)
    g = uint32(c.G)
    b = uint32(c.B)
    a = uint32(c.A)
    return
}
```

What's the reason `r |= r << 8` is used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the the excellent "[The Go image package](http://blog.golang.org/go-image-package)" blogpost:

> [...] the channels have a 16-bit effective range: 100% red is represented by
>   RGBA returning an r of 65535, not 255, so that converting from CMYK or
>   YCbCr is not as lossy. Third, the type returned is uint32, even though
>   the maximum value is 65535, to guarantee that multiplying two values
>   together won't overflow.

and

> Note that the R field of an RGBA is an 8-bit alpha-premultiplied color in the range [0, 255]. RGBA satisfies the Color interface by multiplying that value by 0x101 to generate a 16-bit alpha-premultiplied color in the range [0, 65535]

So if we look at the bit representation of a color with the value `c.R = 10101010` then this operation

```
r = uint32(c.R)
r |= r << 8
```

effectively copies the first byte to the second byte.

```
   00000000000000000000000010101010 (r)
 | 00000000000000001010101000000000 (r << 8)
--------------------------------------
   00000000000000001010101010101010 (r |= r << 8)
```

This is equivalent to a multiplication with the factor `0x101` and distributes all 256 possible values evenly across the range [0, 65535].

Answer (score 8):

The `color.RGBA` type implements the `RGBA` method to satisfy the [`color.Color`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Color) interface:

```
type Color interface {
    // RGBA returns the alpha-premultiplied red, green, blue and alpha values
    // for the color. Each value ranges within [0, 0xffff], but is represented
    // by a uint32 so that multiplying by a blend factor up to 0xffff will not
    // overflow.
    //
    // An alpha-premultiplied color component c has been scaled by alpha (a),
    // so has valid values 0 <= c <= a.
    RGBA() (r, g, b, a uint32)
}
```

Now the RGBA type represents the colour channels with the `uint8` type, giving a range of [0, 0xff].  Simply converting these values to `uint32` would not extend the range up to [0, 0xffff].

An appropriate conversion would be something like:

```
r = uint32((float64(c.R) / 0xff) * 0xffff)
```

However, they want to avoid the floating point arithmetic.  Luckily `0xffff / 0xff` is `0x0101`, so we can simplify the expression (ignoring the type conversions for now):

```
r = c.R * 0x0101
  = c.R * 0x0100 + c.R
  = (c.R << 8) + c.R    # multiply by power of 2 is equivalent to shift
  = (c.R << 8) | c.R    # equivalent, since bottom 8 bits of first operand are 0
```

And that's essentially what the code in the standard library is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Converting a value in the range 0 to 255 (an 8-bit RGB component) to a value in the range 0 to 65535 (a 16-bit RGB component) would be done by multiplying the 8-bit value by 65535/255; 65535/255 is exactly 257, which is hex 101, so multiplying a one-byte by 65535/255 can be done by shifting that byte value left 8 bits and ORing it with the original value.

(There's nothing Go-specific about this; similar tricks are done elsewhere, in other languages, when converting 8-bit RGB/RGBA components to 16-bit RGB/RGBA components.)

Answer (score 2):

To convert from 8- to 16-bits per RGB component, copy the byte into the high byte of the 16-bit value. e.g., 0x03 becomes 0x0303, 0xFE becomes 0xFEFE, so that the 8-bit values 0 through 255 (0xFF) produce 16-bit values 0 to 65,535 (0xFFFF) with an even distribution of values.